# How do you give different AWS resources different permissions to separate MySQL DBs in 1 RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to query 2 DBs (Keys, UserInfo) within 1 MySQL RDS Instance from a Lambda & an ElasticBeanStalk API. I want to give the Lambda R/W access to the Keys DB, and to give the ElasticBeanStalk R/W on UserInfo DB (and all the tables within it). Besides having 2 separate RDS instances and assigning different IAM roles to each, how can I do this?

Comment: Create two users in the MySQL RDS, with different privileges.

Comment: @ceejayoz - can you expand on that please?

Comment: Not much to expand on, really. Create two users in the database itself. Nothing to do with RDS or IAM - this is basic MySQL functionality. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html